# Documents or Desktop not Staying in Favorites in Finder Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, macos

Whenever I add the documents or desktop folder to favorites on macOS Sierra, it stays there for some time but then disappears. Is it a problem with iCloud Drive?

Update: It still occurs in macOS High Sierra. I tried booting into safe mode, resetting PRAM and SMC, resetting finder preferences, but it still doesn't fix the problem.

You can see it here:
https://youtu.be/TJubgY3tUKM

Comment: Same for me. My Desktop sticks ok but not Documents. New MBP, my old one was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what is causing this, but you could try force quitting Finder. Go to the Apple icon in the top left corner and select the `Force Quit` option. A menu will pop up and you can click on Finder to restart it. Also, if you open the Finder preferences you should be able to select which folders appear in the side bar.

Comment: I tried force quitting Finder but the same problem occurred. I also tried the preferences and I was able to see which folder were added to the sidebar. However, when I checked Documents and Desktop, it would glitch and remain unchecked.

Comment: @AmitKulkarni Have you tried restarting the computer and also shutting down manually?

Comment: I have done it before, but the problem still persisted, I will try it again and let you know when my computer turns back on and if it fixed the problem.

Comment: I tried force shutting down by pressing and holding the power button, but the problem still persists.

Comment: @AmitKulkarni Have you tried logging out and logging back in? If there are other users on the machine, have you tried on a different account?

Comment: I tried to log out, but the problem is still there. There are other users on my MacBook Pro, but I unfortunately don't have access to their account. However, I am an admin on my current account.

Comment: @AmitKulkarni do you keep backups of the machine? This might be a lengthy fix but you could try doing a fresh install of the operating system.

Comment: No, I didn't keep backups with time machine because my disk space is almost full. I also don't want to do a fresh install of the operating system because it would take a long time to do and I don't want to lose my data and apps. However, I still keep my laptop up to date with the latest macOS version (10.12.6) and I am not running a beta if that helps.

Comment: @AmitKulkarni when you say your disk space is almost full, do you mean on your machine? Usually you do a back up on an external hard drive. But anyway, you said that you did a hard shutdown. Can you try a restart also? I know you said you have tried it before, but I've had it work in the past. You could also look into resting the PRAM and the NVRAM, although I'm not sure if this is related or not.

Comment: I tried restarting my laptop, but I still can't put the folder on the sidebar. While I do have an external drive capable of holding enough space for the backup, this problem has been there ever since I created my account on this laptop. I actually heard of resetting the PRAM and NVRAM, but I don't think it will help in this situation. I might try it anyway, although it resets some settings but doesn't delete data.

Comment: @AmitKulkarni I'm not sure what to try other than the PRAM and NVRAM settings. If those don't work, I would look into a fresh install of the operating system or trying to get an external drive to try from a back up.

Comment: I will try to reset those settings. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link I found, I was experiencing the same issue. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4283571

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will help preserve your answer for other users who may benefit in future.